# Include only the header filename in c source project with Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, include, include-path

I have a rather large project were different c source files includes header files as

```
#include "headername1.h"
#include "headername2.h"
```

Even thou the header files (see above) **are not** in the same path as the c source files that includes them.

i.e the project structure of the example that I am trying to describe is something like the following

```
project root folder
    module1/
        src1.c    <- #include "headername1.h"   
    module2/
        src2.c    <- #include "headername1.h" & #include "headername2.h"
    common_includes/
        headername1.h
        headername2.h
```

### Notice how the path to the headerfiles are left out. The program still compiles and executes as intended!

I am trying to understand how this is possible and how to do it myself in a totally different project.
I have the following project structure **for testing purposes**:

```
Project folder
    src/
        main.c
    inc/
        main_include.h
    Makefile
```

**inc/main_include.h :**

```
#ifndef __MAIN_INCLUDE_H__
#define __MAIN_INCLUDE_H__

#define A_VALUE     10

#endif /* __MAIN_INCLUDE_H__ */
```

**src/main.c :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if TEST
    /* How to make this work? */
    #include "main_include.h"
#else
    #include "../inc/main_include.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("A_VALUE = %d\n", A_VALUE);
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile :**

```
TARGET  ?= test.out
TEST    ?= 0

ifeq (TEST,1)
# (1) Maybe add something here, but what exactly?
endif

SRC_DIRS :=     \
    src                                 

INC_DIRS :=     \
    inc

# Extract sources and headers
SRCS := $(foreach src_dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.c))

INCS := $(foreach inc_dir,$(INC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(inc_dir)/*.h))

GCC      = gcc
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -O2 -DTEST=$(TEST)
LIBS    :=

ifeq (TEST,1)
# (2) Maybe add something here, but what exactly?
endif

all:
    @$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(SRCS) $(INCS) -o $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f *.out
```

As of now

```
make all TEST=0 && ./test.out
```

works as intended, while

```
make all TEST=1 && ./test.out
```

does not. I am 99.9% sure that I could solve this by adding some functionality inside one or in both of the ifeq statements in the Makefile (symbolic links or something ..?). My problem however is that I am unable to find ("google") any relevant resources or a simple example (I have the rather large project that I am unable to follow).

Can someone provide a "hint" or a simple example on how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Henrik

**Solution (The Makefile):**

```
TARGET  ?= test.out
TEST    ?= 0

GCC     ?= gcc
CFLAGS  ?= -std=c99 -Wall -O2 -DTEST=$(TEST)
LIBS    :=

SRC_DIRS :=     \
    src                                 

INC_DIRS :=     \
    inc

# Extract sources and headers
SRCS := $(foreach src_dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.c))

ifeq ($(TEST),1)
INCS    := $(foreach inc_dir,$(INC_DIRS),-I$(inc_dir))
else
INCS    := $(foreach inc_dir,$(INC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(inc_dir)/*.h))
endif

all:
    @$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(SRCS) $(INCS) -o $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f *.out
```

Comment: You are referring to some "this" in your question, which is presumably is your problem. But you never tell us what is "this".

Comment: I want to be able to compile and run my project with make all TEST=1 && ./test.out. Which probably  requires some additional adjustments in the Makefile. See the ifeq statement in src/main.c for details regarding what TEST=1 does.

Comment: This is how it works: If you have a directory in your includes path, the n any file in it or any relative path to it can be included using `#include`. If you want to include only files in the source directory you should not add any other directories to the includes path.

Comment: The problem isnt the #include statement itself but how to remove the need to declare the path to the headerfile

Comment: You should move your `INC_DIRS` definitions into the conditional in the makefile.

Comment: Adding `-I../inc` to your INCS or your CC command line will allow you to `#include "some-header-file.h"` from any directory listed with `-I`

Comment: @cleblanc This should be put into an answer, don't you think? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding -I../inc to your INCS or your CC command line will allow you to #include "some-header-file.h" from any directory listed with -I